# Passing spinner values

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'm trying to code a way to pass the values from two spinners into another activity.

I found examples using the putExtra method online but I'm having trouble implementing it myself (I think I'm just unclear on how it works exactly).

The code I have is (without any values in the putExtra method, because that's the bit I'm stuck on):

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

        transportSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.transportSpinner);
        locationSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.locationSpinner);

        buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              Intent i = new Intent(GetDirections.this.getApplicationContext(), DirectionDisplay.class);
              i.putExtra(); 
              GetDirections.this.startActivity(i);

          }

        });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? For example, what are you packaging into the `Intent`?

Comment: which adapter are you using with spinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your spinners are correctly populated, you can do:

```
...
i.putExtra("transportSpinnerSelected", transportSpinner.getSelectedItem());
i.putExtra("locationSpinnerSelected", locationSpinner.getSelectedItem());
...
```

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. It would be nice if you marked the answer as correct, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Building on gwa's answer:

On this screen in the intent you need to do (assuming your spinners have the correct values of course):

```
Intent i = new Intent(GetDirections.this.getApplicationContext(), DirectionDisplay.class);
i.putExtra("transportSpinnerValue", transportSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
i.putExtra("locationSpinnerValue", locationSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
GetDirections.this.startActivity(i);
```

Then in the next screen, you have to retrieve those values. Since you passed the extra information in the Intent, you have to get it from the intent in the next class.

So do:

```
//DirectionsDisplay class
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String transportItemChosen = extras.getString("transportSpinnerValue");
    String locationItemChosen = extras.getString("locationSpinnerValue");

}
```

Comment: You are both heroes, heroes of coding and of android. Cheers.